# apex select list, get user data

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I've created a select list item and need to reference this list on another page. how do i get the user input, place it in a variable that can be used to calculate the total value of the selected item on another page?

code for the select list which is displayed on a report to allow for amount to be stated:

```
select item_id, 
   itemname, 
  item_price, 
   apex_item.hidden(1, item_id) ||
      apex_item.hidden(2, item_price) || 
      apex_item.select_list(
          p_idx           =>   3,
          p_value         =>   nvl(null,'item'),
          p_list_values   =>   '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10',
          p_show_null     =>   'YES',
          p_null_value    =>   0,
          p_null_text     =>   '0',
          p_item_id       =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
          p_item_label    =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
          p_show_extra    =>   'NO') "item"
          from item
```

the select to display the sum will look something like this:

```
  select itemname,
  item_price, 
  'select list value',
  ('select list value'* item_price) as sum
  from item
```

how do i get the chosen amount from the select list?

Thanks

Comment: The question doesn't seem clear for me. Do I undestand your flow correclty: a user sees the report with the select list, chooses a value, then is redirected to another page, and another page uses this value for further calculations?

Comment: yes that is the flow, i'm using a wizard to progress to the pages and i need the final summary page to display the second select query which uses the select list value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle APEX has package `APEX_APPLICATION` which contains collections with names from `G_F01` to `G_F50`. When you use any function from `apex_item` to create an item inside a report, you pass a number into `p_idx` parameter. In your example it is `3` for the select list. This value corresponds to one of collections mentioned above - `G_F03` in this case.

All values from user's input are passed to these collections after the submit. So you can to write in the after submit process following code:

```
for i in apex_application.g_f01.first .. apex_application.g_f01.last loop
  insert into my_table (id, new_value) 
  values (apex_application.g_f01(i), apex_application.g_f03(i));
end loop;
```

This code shows how to insert values from user's input into `my_table`. Note, that these collections contain only rows changed by user. If a user gets a report with 10 rows and changes 3 of them, each collection will have 3 elements.

Also, APEX has APEX_COLLECTION API to store temporary data.

For more information, see in the documentation: [APEX_APPLICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_APPLICATION.htm#GUID-46D9B879-3180-480D-B5D6-54AABDD146F6), [APEX_COLLECTION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_COLLECTION.htm#GUID-859B488C-2628-44D7-969F-50872C685B76).

**UPD.**
There are two ways to work with the data further - using a table or `APEX_COLLECTION`. I have never worked with `APEX_COLLECTION`, so here is an example with a table.
If you use a table to store temporary data, you need columns for `ID`, user's name and data (data from the Select List in your example). On the page with the report you need to do this after the submit:

```
delete from my_table where user_name = :APP_USER;

for i in apex_application.g_f01.first .. apex_application.g_f01.last loop
  insert into my_table (id, new_value, user_name) 
  values (apex_application.g_f01(i), apex_application.g_f03(i), :APP_USER);
end loop;
```

On the next page, where you need to use this data, you create the following report:

```
select t.new_value, ...
  from my_table t, ... <other tables>
 where t.user_name = :APP_USER
   and t.id = ...
   and <other conditions>
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, sorry if i'm being dumb but in-relation to my second query and the for loop you've provided me how would i combine these two elements to make my query? thanks

Comment: Will your users select more than one row? If no, you can store the value just in an Application Item. If yes, there are some possibilities...

Comment: they will be selecting the quantity for however many items they want, which can be one item or several. I'm just unsure how and where to implement the code you have given me?

Comment: I added some additional explanations, hope it's clear.